# Need to clearInterval in iframe from parent and it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm using setInterval inside an iframe, and I need to be able to stop it from the parent window, and it doesn't seem to be working. I'm assigning a global variable ('modelViewRefresh') to the setInterval event to be accessed from the parent.

I'm using this code in the parent to try and trigger clearInterval, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var modelViewRefresh = document.getElementById(widget_id + '_iframe').contentWindow['modelViewRefresh'];
console.log("modelViewRefresh=" + modelViewRefresh); // this equals 2 for some reason
clearInterval( modelViewRefresh );
```

I'm even trying this directly:

```
clearInterval( document.getElementById(widget_id + '_iframe').contentWindow['modelViewRefresh'] );
```

I've opened the iframe in a window of its own to verify that the variable is being created (by looking in the DOM via Firebug). FYI it's not a different domain...

I'm mainly using jQuery elsewhere, but read somewhere that it's best to use 'raw' javascript in this instance. So I'm open to a jQuery solution too.

Any ideas? Maybe I am going about it wrong...

PS. I'd also like to be able to start the 'refresh' again from the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Both `clearInterval` and `clearTimeout` require the `iframe name` when called from outside the iframe.

HTML Example : `<iframe name="iframe_0"></iframe>`

JS Example :

`iframe_0.clearInterval(modelViewRefresh)`

To restart from the parent : `modelViewRefresh=iframe_0.setInterval(do_this,1000)`

Answer (score 0):

Iframes have their own `window` object, meaning even if a variable is global in the iframe, it won't be accessible in the parent because parent and iframe do not share the same `window`.

If you want to invoke a function in the iframe from the parent, I suggest you have a look at [JSChannel](https://github.com/mozilla/jschannel) or the [jQuery postMessage](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) plugin. It might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look :)

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?